# Unable to debug in Visual Studio because process can not access file

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mahapps.metro

When I try to debug in Visual Studio I get the error message:

> Unable to copy file "C:\Users\Name\Dropbox\Company Name\Development\Product Name 4 - Release Candidate\packages\MahApps.Metro.1.1.2.0\lib\net45\MahApps.Metro.dll" to "bin\Debug\MahApps.Metro.dll". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\MahApps.Metro.dll' because it is being used by another process.    Product Name 4 - Release Candidate

How can I fix this error?

Comment: try to remove the reference. copy dll to your bin folder and add a reference from your bin folder to the specific dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens all the time in Dropbox.  Dropbox does some occasional (very brief) locking of files as it is indexing them, and if you happen to attempt to open a file handle with the write attribute set at the same moment, the program will receive a file I/O exception (this can happen to your own code as well, so if you regularly work in Dropbox, be sure to handle that gracefully).

Try compiling/running it again and see if the problem goes away.  If not, then you likely still have an instance of your application running in the background.  This can occur if your program ever forks.  VS will terminate the original process, but often not forked processes from it.  Check task manager to be sure.  It will be listed as a background process in Windows 8/8.1

Comment: Good to know that Dropbox was the probable cause. I waited a bit and then restarted VS. Then I tried debugging again and didn't receive any error.